# WPF Clearing Validation in BindingGroup

Tags: wpf, validation, binding

I have a class called Contact that has 2 string properties: "Name" and "PhoneNumber".

My ViewModel has an observable collection of these contacts and there is a ComboBox that has it's ItemsSource bound to this collection .

I have a WPF Grid whose DataContext is set to the ComboBox's SelectedItem property. This Grid has a BindingGroup that contains a ValidationRule to validate the text properties of my "contact" class.

This is my Grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContainerGrid" Grid.Column="0"
    Background="Transparent"
    LostFocus="ContainerGrid_LostFocus"
    ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
    <Grid.BindingGroup>
        <BindingGroup x:Name="TextInputBindingGroup" SharesProposedValues="True">
            <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
                <local:TextInputValidationRule />
            </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
        </BindingGroup>
    </Grid.BindingGroup>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Name:" />
        <TextBox x:Name="PersonName" Text="{Binding Path=PersonName, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="Phone Number:" />
        <TextBox x:Name="PhoneNumber" Text="{Binding Path=PhoneNumber, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

If the data for the contact was invalid (the name and/or phone number was missing) the grid containing the elements for editing these properties is highlighted in red and it's tool tip is set to the first error.

If I then delete the invalid Contact, the grid remains outlined in red with the tool tip displaying the error for the item that was deleted even though the grid is now displaying another, valid item.

How do I clear the errors shown in the grid?

Thanks,

-Frinny

Comment: It sounds like you either need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) on your `Contact` class and view model and/or use an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the `List<T>` in the view model. They both help with updating the UI of changes to the data from code behind or view model.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I have already implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface for my contact class.

Comment: To fix this problem I had to call the method that validates the UI after deleting the invalid contact.